# How can I get an image widget to center in the footer of my WordPress site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, centering

I am using the Kale Wordpress theme, and in the footer, I used an image widget for my logo. I am trying to center this image using the Additional CSS panel under customize. I believe my centering code is correct, and that I am just having trouble identifying the proper Selector or class to let CSS know what I am trying to center.

I tried using Inspect Element in Chrome to find what it says is the class name for the image but to no avail.

```
.image wp-image-14  attachment-medium size-medium .footer-row-3-widget widget widget_media_image {
  display: block;
margin: 0 auto;  }
```

If it helps my website is [revoltmedia.org](https://revoltmedia.org), and I am trying to center the logo at the bottom. Again I think the code I have for centering the image is fine, I am just having trouble figuring out what the name of the class/selector is for the image so I can actually call it, and center the image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The footer seems to have an `id` for this widget (`#media_image-3`) so that could be your selector to use `text-align: center;`

Comment: If you want to specifically target only this image, you can use a more specific selector like `#media_image-3 > img.image` and then you can use the properties you have (i.e. `display:block; margin: 0 auto;`)

Comment: @ochi Thank you! using #media_image-3 worked! For the future how were you able to find out what the id was for the image?

Comment: Nevermind when using inspect element I see, div id and then media_image-3. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Yes, I used the inspector to give me a closer look at the elements involved with (and around) the image - I added an answer then.  For future reference, it's good practice to add a [mcve] to your question

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML with Chrome's dev tools (`inspect`) I can see that the `footer` seems to have an `id` for this widget (`#media_image-3`) so that could be your selector to use `text-align: center;`

Now, if you want to specifically target only this image (and none other), you can use a more specific selector like `#media_image-3 > img.image` and then you can use the properties you already have, like

```
#media_image-3 > img.image {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.footer-row-3-widget widget widget_media_image {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what worked was using the id #media_image-3.

Comment: @LiamRamsey please make sure you come back and select an answer as the one that help you solved the issue